# Playscape 1.11 SDK integration - Unable to convert classes into dex format

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

After upgrading to the currently latest version (1.10) I am unnable to build the game. 
The error message appears while trying to convert classes into dex format.
There are two errors in console log:

- > CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
- > Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.

Seems like android support lib is included twice.. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Here are the details of these two errors:

1. [dropbox.com/s/mx8uc1z1pwo4wl0/1.txt](http://dropbox.com/s/mx8uc1z1pwo4wl0/1.txt)
2. [dropbox.com/s/p6mgogn2cxidrep/2.txt](http://dropbox.com/s/p6mgogn2cxidrep/2.txt)

Comment: Please include the details in your question, and not as dropbox links.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue several times myself. The error should be related to having two "android-support-v4.jar" files in your Assets/Plugins/Android folder, one likely is installed by facebook's sdk, another one by playscape's sdk. They are likely placed in different places within the folder structure under Assets/Plugins/Android.
So I would recommend trying to do a search in your Assets/Plugins/Android folder for that file, remove one of them and the problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks! That's' exactly the solution to my problem :)